# Is payment in installments Halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Example situation

**Person A** is purchasing a computer. The computer costs $410. But the **person A** has only $50 in his pocket. The seller is offering to the person to repay the rest $360 of money during the next 6 months as the **person A** receives monthly salary.

```
Month      Payment
-------------------
1          $60
2          $60
3          $60
4          $60
5          $60
6          $60
-------------------
Total      $360
```

**Is this type of sales Halal?**

Both sides, the seller and the person, are agreeing on the terms.

Doesn't this violate the hadith

> From Usamah ibn Zayd : The Prophet, , said: "There is no riba **except
> in Nasiyah [waiting].**" (Bukhari, Kitab al-Buyu', Bab Bay' al-dinari
> bi al-dinar nasa'an; also Muslim and Musnad Ahmad) "There is no riba
> in hand-to-hand [spot] transactions." (Muslim, Kitab al-Musaqat, Bah
> bay'i al-ta'ami mithlan bi mithlin; also in Nasa'i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, a transaction will be permissible if completed without incurring any interest charges. So if it is fixed amount (as in example) and agreed upon then its fine.

[Check this explanation for EMI(Equated monthly Installments)](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/40939)

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is a case of selling on credit, and such a sale is permissible.

> #### اشترى رسول الله صلى الله عليه طعاما من يهودي بنسيئة ورهنة درعاً له من حديد
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) bought some foodstuff (barley) from a Jew on credit and mortgaged his iron armor to him
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/35/12)</sup>

Comment: I too red this hadith. And in this case the holy prophet SAW mortgaged his iron armor. So basically He used the iron armor as money. Or he bartered it to the barley, pay attention. I am just very afraid to qualify the transaction in my example Halal?

Comment: @Bahrom No he did not barter or use it as money, he gave his armor as security for the loan and had it returned on payment.